# How do I know which TextVIew pressed in a TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I hava a `TableLayout` contains several `TableRow`, each `TableRow`has three `TextView`.

The problem is when I press a certain `TextView`, how do I know which one is pressed?

should I set a `OnClickListener` for every `TextView`? I don't like it this way :(

Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: i think i'll use gridview instead

Answer (score 1):

u check onClickListener source. just like in Titanium Application

```
tableLayout.addEventListener('click',function(event){
event.source.value = <change>;
});
```

It is just a logic. Through this help u check it.

Answer (score 0):

u check onClickListener source. just like in Titanium Application

```
tableLayout.addEventListener('click',function(event){
event.source.value = <change>;
});
```

It is just a logic. Through this help u check it.